# ruby mechanize in Facebook

Tags: ruby, facebook, screen-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to click the Settings button on the home page, but when I do I get this page back:

```
#<WWW::Mechanize::Page
 {url
  #<URI::HTTP:0x1023c5fc0 URL:http://www.facebook.com/editaccount.php?ref=mb&drop>}
 {meta}
{title nil}
{iframes}
{frames}
{links}
{forms}>
```

which is.. kinda empty! Is there some problems with these iframes and frames stuff maybe?

Comment: I noticed it does some kind of redirect on a https connection... that's the problem I think.. what do you think?

Answer (score 3):

As roja mentioned, following redirects might be what you need. Here's an example of how to do this:

```
@agent = Mechanize.new
@agent.redirect_ok = :all
@agent.follow_meta_refresh = :anywhere
```

Then you can pretty much ignore the fact that there's redirects involved - Mechanize will simply put you on the resulting page.

Comment: If someone else has provided a mostly-sufficient answer, best to edit their answer (when your rep. is high enough), or present the most-correct answer without being so referential.... i.e. be complete in your own answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I've worked this example into Roja's initial answer.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook redirects me to: https://register.facebook.com/editaccount.php which I assume is the final destination. Assuming that WWW::Mechanize is set up to follow https redirects you should end up there too.

Much of facebook like most modern websites is generated by javascript which I think that WWW::Mechanize is unable to cope with, this could be the source of your problem. I recommend trying to scrape while appending "?_fb_noscript=1" to the url's you visit. This turns off much of facebooks javascript system and should enable a smoother ride for your little bot.

(Do remember this is only an idea and doubtless whatever you do is against facebooks usage policy and this makes you a "baddy." I don't condone such badness and beleve that baddies should be forced to go to bed early etc... *ad nauseum*)

Comment: =) I was just trying to programmatically switch off my email notifications so that when I'm getting too many I disable them for a while.. bye the way, I didn't find mention of https in Mechanize RDoc.. so is it set to follow https redirects by default?